# How can I refresh only a specific table when I press a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this table:

[image]

The results of the table are from data base. If I add a new "nombre proyecto" and I press "guardar" I am adding a new data in my table and I only can see the new data if I reload the page , but I only want refresh the table to see the new data when I press a button.

The function that complete the table:

```
    GridProyectos: function(data){

    var self = this;

    $.each(data, function(index,value){ 
        var historial = JSON.stringify(value); 
            $('#grid_proyecto').append(
                '<tr>'+
                    '<td>'+value.id_proyecto+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+value.nombre_proyecto+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+value.fecha_registro+'</td>'+
                    '<td>'+value.proyecto_oculto+'</td>'+
                '</tr>'
            );   
        }); 
},
```

And the template with the html:

```
'<div id="legend">'+
          '<legend class="">Nuevo proyecto</legend>'+
        '</div>'+
             '<button type="button" class = "btn btn-default btn-xs add" id ="addPro_id"><img src="img/addPro.png" height="30" width="30"/></button>'+
            '<div class="form-group" id ="addProyecto_id">'+
                    '<label for="concept" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre proyecto</label>'+
                    '<div class="col-sm-9">'+
                        '<input type="text" class="form-control" id="nuevo_proyecto_id" name="nuevo_proyecto">'+
                    '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
             '<div class="form-group" id ="btn_pro_id">'+
                '<div class="col-sm-12 text-right">'+
                    '<button type="button" id="btn_enviar_proyecto_id" class="btn btn-primary enviar">Guardar</button>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+

             '<div class="form-group">'+
                '<div class="container-fluid">'+
                    '<div class="row">'+
                        '<div class="col-md-12">'+
                            '<table id="grid-basic" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">'+
                                '<thead>'+
                                    '<tr>'+
                                        '<th data-column-id>Id</th>'+
                                        '<th data-column-id>Nombre</th>'+
                                        '<th data-column-id>Fecha registro</th>'+
                                        '<th data-column-id>proyecto oculto</th>'+
                                    '</tr>'+
                                '</thead>'+
                                '<tbody id ="grid_proyecto">'+

                                '</tbody>'+
                            '</table>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</div>'+
```

How can I do this? thanks and sorry my english.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a syntax error in your markup.  In the code you copied here you have `id ="grid_proyecto"`.  Try removing that space `id="grid_proyecto"`, and see if that works.  The jQuery append function should be what you're looking for in this case.  Just make sure that `$('#grid_proyecto')` has a `length` > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ideal thing to do is append the new data to the table, meanwhile the real insert in database is loading. You can append it the same way that you were doing it. I recomend you to create a specific function that will do that append, like this:

```
function agregarTabla(value){
        $('#grid_proyecto').append(
            '<tr>'+
                '<td>'+value.id_proyecto+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+value.nombre_proyecto+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+value.fecha_registro+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+value.proyecto_oculto+'</td>'+
            '</tr>'
        );  
}
```

So you can call it with the new data.

But, if you really want to refresh that part anyway, no matter what, you can use [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/). In your case you will have to do this:

`$("#grid_proyecto").load("URL_OF_YOUR_PROJECT" + #grid_proyecto")`

That way you will only refresh that small part of the web.

Hope that helps.

Sorry for my english too.